# Mapping entity having dependency with two different schema's on microservice architecture

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, microservices

Based on Microservice architecture I have separated the two schemes into two different db's see below,

- (VS2015 Solution1, BusinessEntity project) db1 -> schema1 -> customer, supplier
- (VS2015 Solution2, BusinessEntity project) db2 -> schema2 -> product, order, orderdetails

**C#**
Now I am having the issue when creating the mapping entity how and where should I create the mapping entity.

> I am using "PostgreSQL" as my DB and "Fluent nHibernate"

```
public class CustomerOrderMap
{
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
// (pkey property)
public virtual int Id  { get; set; } 

// (fk property, this is in db1, schema1)
public virtual int CustomerId     { get; set; } 
public virtual Customer Customer  { get; set; }

// (fk property, this is in db2, schema2)
public virtual int OrderId    { get; set; }
public virtual Order Order    { get; set; }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Where should I have this entity?
2. Since I am following Microservice architecture I am having the "Order" entity separately in schema2. Hence how can I have that entity type in the mapping entity if I am going to have the mapping entity in schema1 or am I missing something in architecture wise?

*any examples would be appreciated!!*

Thanks.

Comment: One more thing to consider is the usecase. Say this data is needed for some analytical purpose( seeing which region/customer age  buys product X Or is to serve customer traffic (showing his purchases) ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of Microservice architecture is to isolate functionality in separate distinct bounded contexts.  From you example you've got 2 bounded contexts (schema 1 and schema 2).  You don't share domain objects across those domains.  You may share the Id's, but you are going to have to go back to the microservice that owns the domain object to populate it.

Comment: _You may share the Id's, but you are going to have to go back to the microservice that owns the domain object to populate it._ is this the only way to handle this kind of scenario? and also does my issue fit in a Microservice architecture or any (please specify)

Comment: I don't know your whole domain, so i can't really comment on whether the decision to use microservices is good or not.  Here's a nice explanation with diagram.  http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305469/microservices-architecture-and-bounded-contexts.  for the most part, I'm of the mind that you've got a microservice per bounded context.